# Using AnimatedVectorDrawables to make the Android robo wave

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to create a simple animation of the Android robot logo waving. I have my `VectorDrawable` and `AnimatedVectorDrawable` defined as below:

VectorDrawable (drawable/android.xml)

```
<vector android:height="240dp" android:viewportHeight="345.0"
    android:viewportWidth="294.0" android:width="240dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#a4c639"
        android:pathData="M206.62,4.72L206.62,4.72A6.5,6.5 57.81,0 1,209.16 13.56L173.77,77.4A6.5,6.5 76.8,0 1,164.93 79.94L164.93,79.94A6.5,6.5 76.8,0 1,162.4 71.1L197.79,7.26A6.5,6.5 57.81,0 1,206.62 4.72z"
        android:strokeColor="#FFF" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#a4c639"
        android:pathData="M74.07,7.53L74.07,7.53A6.5,6.5 112,0 1,82.9 10.06L118.29,73.91A6.5,6.5 124.14,0 1,115.76 82.74L115.76,82.74A6.5,6.5 124.14,0 1,106.92 80.21L71.53,16.36A6.5,6.5 112,0 1,74.07 7.53z"
        android:strokeColor="#FFF" android:strokeWidth="1"/>

    <path
        android:name="leftArm"
        android:fillColor="#ff0000"
        android:pathData="M28,111L28,111A24,24 0,0 1,52 135L52,220A24,24 0,0 1,28 244L28,244A24,24 0,0 1,4 220L4,135A24,24 0,0 1,28 111z"
        />

    <path android:fillColor="#a4c639" android:pathData="M56,111a91,84 0,1 0,182 0a91,84 0,1 0,-182 0z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#a4c639" android:pathData="M78,90L216,90A22,22 0,0 1,238 112L238,250A22,22 0,0 1,216 272L78,272A22,22 0,0 1,56 250L56,112A22,22 0,0 1,78 90z"/>
    <path
        android:name="rightArm"
        android:fillColor="#00f"
        android:pathData="M264,111L264,111A24,24 0,0 1,288 135L288,220A24,24 0,0 1,264 244L264,244A24,24 0,0 1,240 220L240,135A24,24 0,0 1,264 111z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#FFF" android:pathData="m52,114.5h190"
        android:strokeColor="#FFF" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M105,70m-4,0a4,4 0,1 1,8 0a4,4 0,1 1,-8 0"
        android:strokeColor="#FFF" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M189,70m-4,0a4,4 0,1 1,8 0a4,4 0,1 1,-8 0"
        android:strokeColor="#FFF" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

AnimatedVectorDrawable (drawable/wave.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/android">

    <target
        android:animation="@animator/waveanim"
        android:name="leftArm"/>


</animated-vector>
```

and heres animator/waveanim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:propertyName="pivotX"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="50.0"
        />

</set>
```

I did previously try a few different things, such as wrapping the "leftArm" path in a `<group>` and trying to animated random properties. I was able to get some random movements but nothing like what I was going for, so I scrapped that code and went back to the beginning.

Btw, heres a screenie of what it looks like currently:

http://prntscr.com/bk5e53

So how can I make the arm wave at me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you wave at the Android maybe it will just wave back...

However, in case that doesn't work, here's how to approach it.

First, it's always useful to have the [official documentation handy for reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html). From here we can see that `android:rotation` is a property of the `<group>` tag, so you were going down the correct path when you wrapped the left arm in a `<group>` tag, you *will* need to do that.

The other properties to be aware of are `pivotX` and `pivotY`. Again I can see that `pivotX` appears in your question, but not where it should be! The pivot point of a group determines what part of the graphic is the centre of the rotation. So if you consider for example, a square. If the pivot point is in the centre, imagine sticking a pin in the middle and spinning the square around it. If the pivot point was the top left, imagine sticking a pin right in that corner and making the whole square swing around the pinned corner.

In your case you probably want to work out the coordinates for the middle of the shoulder and set that as your pivot. Your pivot point stays where it is; the rotation changes.

So that part of your VectorDrawable would look something like this:

```
...
<group
  android:name="leftArmGroup"
  android:pivotX=     //the x and y coordinates of the shoulder
  android:pivotY=     //
  android:rotation="0">
    <path
    android:name="leftArm"
    android:fillColor="#ff0000"
    android:pathData="M28,111L28,111A24,24 0,0 1,52 135L52,220A24,24 0,0 1,28 244L28,244A24,24 0,0 1,4 220L4,135A24,24 0,0 1,28 111z"
    />
</group>
...
```

Your animated vector will now need to target `leftArmGroup` instead of `leftArm` and your objectAnimator will be animating `android:propertyName="rotation"` property(in degrees, eg. 0 to 360 would be a full rotation). The 'rotation=0' part that I've included in the snippet above doesn't technically need to be there(zero is default), but it's handy to have so you can quickly try different numbers and see how it looks in the preview window.

Let me know if you want further detail on anything.

Comment: Ok cool, it's good to know I was on the right path. I'll play around with the properties you mentioned and report back.

Comment: Another quick question, is there a simple way to determine the proper pivot x/y coordinate? Or is it just trial and error?

Comment: Don't know if there's necessarily a simple way(unless you drew it yourself and your graphics package shows coordinates perhaps). I'm not at a computer to check but from looking at it I would guess x 28, y 135

Comment: Yea, I realized the first svg M command specified the starting point so anything around there seems to work alright. My issue now tho is the arm seems to get cut-off...ive tried adjusting both android:width and viewportWidth to no avail: https://gyazo.com/32cb9a8e9440659635598341b1d1e43d

Comment: Ah, yeah width is added on to the right-hand side, so that would work if it was the other arm! What you can do in this case is add android:width and viewportWidth then move the whole android to the right. To do this, put the whole android inside a `<group>` tag and use the 'android:translateX' property to move the group to the right.

Comment: Ah that did it, good thinking. I have the arm raising and then returning to its original position. I guess I just need to add some more animations in an animatorset to create a waving back and forth animation correct? If so, I guess my main question is answered, ill mark your answer now.

Comment: Great! Yeah you can just add more objectAnimators to that same set if you want it to do a more complicated wave.